# How to i split a String by first and last character in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of strings

`my_list = ['1Jordan1', '2Michael2', '3Jesse3']`.

If I should delete the first and last character, how would I do it in python??

Comment: `new_list = [ ele[1:-1] for ele in old_list]`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly:

```
mylist = ['1Jordan1', '2Michael2', '3Jesse3']

mylist = list(map(lambda item: item[1:-1], mylist))

print(mylist) # ['Jordan', 'Michael', 'Jesse']
```

This uses slice syntax to get the characters between the first and last character, and uses `map` to apply the slice to each string in the list.

If you'd like something slightly more readable (thanks to the comments), use a list comprehension:

```
mylist = ['1Jordan1', '2Michael2', '3Jesse3']

mylist = [item[1:-1] for item in mylist]

print(mylist) # ['Jordan', 'Michael', 'Jesse']
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use slicing. I would use `[1:-1]`.

Comment: giving an example on OP input will be benefical

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post.  Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24056137).